# Spring configuration for multiple destinations and consumers

Tags: spring, jms, containers, messaging

I'm using a message listener container with one destination and one Consumer (message listener):

```
<bean id="msgListenerContainer"

  class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer" 

  p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"

  p:destination-ref="destination"

  p:messageListener-ref="messageHandler"

  p:concurrentConsumers="10"

  p:maxConcurrentConsumers="50"

  p:receiveTimeout="5000"

  p:idleTaskExecutionLimit="10"

  p:idleConsumerLimit="5" />
```

If i want multiple destinations and for each destination one message listener, what should i do? 
And if i want multiple listener for one destination, what should i do?

Comment: `multiple destinations and for each destination listener` is simple because every listener have ONE destination. `multiple listener for one destination` do you mean TOPIC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You need to define each Message Listener and producer in your spring application context as beans. Something like this:

```
    <!-- MESSAGE LISTENER CONTAINER -->
<bean id="ListListenerContainer"
    class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="qcf" />
    <property name="destinationResolver" ref="JmsDestinationResolver" />
    <property name="receiveTimeout" value="${jms-timeout}" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="${jms-list-topic}" />
    <property name="concurrency" value="1" />
    <property name="pubSubDomain" value="true" />
    <property name="subscriptionDurable" value="${jms-durable-flag}"/>
    <property name="durableSubscriptionName" value="${jms-list-durable-name}" />
    <property name="clientId" value="${jms-list-client-id}"/>
    <property name="sessionTransacted" value="true"/>
</bean> 


<bean id="publisher-1" class="com.stack.overflow.JmsPublisherImpl">
    <constructor-arg ref="jmsTemplate" />
</bean>
```

2) Then you can set the relevant producers using Autowiring or defined in app context(see below) on the class that will handle the message. i.e the class that the Message Listener bean ref above points to:

```
<bean id="messageListener" class="com.stack.overflow.MessageHandler">
        <property name="publisher" ref="publisher-1" />
</bean>
```

This is just 1-2-1 mapping. For any other routing you can add more than one publisher (like above), then it is up to you how you implement the required routing logic to decide which topic/Queues should publish a Message received from Consumer 1 etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your answer; But i can't get it: how can  i have multiple messageListener that registered in a ListenerContainer?  I am new to JMS and HornetQ, tell me in more details please.

Comment: Why you need multiple message listener registered? If those listeners are in different type, your application behavior will be unpredictable.  If they are of the same type, why not simply adjust the concurrent consumer setting in the container?

Comment: Probably because he doesn't know it exists.  https://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html might help.  If you are using annotations you can do like so: @JmsListener(destination = "filter_mailbox", containerFactory = "myFactory", concurrency = "10-50")