# Multiple consumer for one JMS queue

Tags: java, spring, jms, activemq-classic

I am new to JMS. I created basic producer-queue-consumer scenario using tutorial [here](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-jms-activemq)

Here I have configured one producer and one consumer. If I want to add multiple consumers then is it possible ?
I do not want to make it topic so that "every" consumer will get it. I want to configure multiple consumers but "only one" will actually receive it.

Something like having 10 servants. Task can be picked up by any servant. But by only 1 servants.

Two options
1) 10 instance of one class.
2) 1 instance of 10 different classes

Is it possible to achieve any of above two options ? If yes how ?

Currently consumer is configured as follows

`

```
<bean class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
    <property name="destinationName" value="myQueue" />
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
</bean>`
```

**Answer**
Yes it is possible; As suggested by JB Nizet in this comment below.

1) Option 1 i.e. 10 instance of one class.

Achieved by setting "concurrentConsumers" property. There will be only 1 instance of class but there will be 10 receiver threads using same object

`<bean name="anotherListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="myQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="anotherMessageReceiver" />`

2) Option 2 i.e. 1/more instance of different classes

I Created multiple instances of SimpleMessageListenerContainer

`<bean id="messageReceiver" class="com.consumption.JmsMessageReceiver"/>
<bean id="anotherMessageReceiver" class="com.consumption.AnotherJmsMessageReceiver"/>
    <bean name="listener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="myQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="messageReceiver" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="2"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean name="anotherListener" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
        <property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
        <property name="destinationName" value="myQueue" />
        <property name="messageListener" ref="anotherMessageReceiver" />
        <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="2"></property>
    </bean>`

I put the debug in `onMessage` method and observed that specified number of threads were created.

Comment: The javadoc says: *It creates a fixed number of JMS Sessions to invoke the listener*. It also has this method: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers-int-

Comment: Did you try something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12814547/spring-configuration-for-multiple-destinations-and-consumers ??

Comment: @JBNizet it worked. Can you please add it as an answer so I can accept it. Meanwhile is second option possible i.e. 1 instance of 10 different classes?

Comment: @KaushikLele why would you want that? Messages would randomly go to one or the other instance, and there's really no reason to treat the messages randomly differently. Note, BTW, that Spring doesn't create 10 instances of the listener. It just calls you unique listener concurrently. Your listener must be thread-safe.

Comment: @JBNizet no practical scenario, thinking it theoretically while learning basics. Thanks you pointed out that it is multiple threads and not multiple objects. But that is what I was looking for. I have updated question with those details.